# the proof of an elementary problem in trignometry

Tags: inequality

how do I prove the following?

$$\sin a_1 + \sin a_2 + \ldots + \sin a_n \lt n\sin\frac{k}{n}$$

where $k=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j$.

I can't do it by using the inequality of A.M. and G.M

err..here all the angles are ACUTE

Comment: Do you mean to have a greater than or equals sign (or a less than or equals sign since the edit)?  This is false when $n=1$

Comment: $0=\sin(0)+\sin(\pi)<2\cdot \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=2$, so it should not be a greater than or equal sign.  $0=\sin(2\pi)+\sin(\pi)>2\cdot \sin(\frac{3\pi}{2})=-2$ so it is false for less than or equal sign as well.  Check the problem statement to see if you are missing some additional constraints, otherwise either interpretation of the problem is false.

Comment: @JMoravitz I forgot to mention that **all angles mentioned are acute**

Comment: If $f''(x)$ exists and is non-positive  for $x\in [a,b]$ and if $w_1,...,w_n$ are  positive  then for $x_1,...,x_n\in [a,b]$ we have $\sum_1^n w_if(x_i)\leq f(y)\sum_1^nw_i$  where $y= (\sum_1^nw_ix_1)/\sum_1^nw_i.$ Use the MVT for $ f$ and for $ f'$.

Answer (score 1):

As JMoravitz noted, the inequality is not true.

However, if one assumes that $a_1,\dots,a_n \in [0,\pi/2]$, an interval where $\sin (\cdot)$ is concave,  then it follows that

$$\sin (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j )\ge \frac 1n \sum_{j=1}^n \sin (a_j).$$

More generally, this is true when all (nonzero) $a_j$'s are on an interval where $\sin$ is concave.

Note however that if we take $a_1,\dots,a_n \in [-\pi/2,0]$, where $\sin$ is convex, the sign of the inequality above changes.

Comment: can you prove the above statement? it is a bit unclear to me

Comment: [An article on convex and concave functions](http://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/cv1/t)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f''$ exist on an open interval containing $[a,b]$ and let $f''(x)\leq 0$ for $x\in [a,b].$ Let $x_1,...,x_n\in [a,b].$ Let $w_1,..,w_n>0$ with $\sum_1^nw_i=1.$ Then $\sum_1^nw_if(x_i)\leq f(\sum^n_0w_i x_i).$

Proof. Case $n=1$ is trivial. The case $x_1=x_i$ for all i from $1$ to $n$ is  also trivial. We prove  case $n=2$ with $x_1\ne x_2$ and then show that case $n>2$ can reduce to case $n=2$ by induction on $n$.

For $ n=2$  and $x_1< x_2$ the statement is equivalent to the assertion that  the graph of $f(x)$ for $x\in [x_1,x_2]$ has no point below the line segment joining $(x_1,f(x_1))$ to $(x_2,f(x_2)).$

By contradiction : Let $y=w_1x_1+w_2x_2$ and suppose $f(y)<w_1f(x_1)+w_2f_(x_2).$ $$ \text {Then }\quad  s_1<s_2 \text { where}$$ $$s_1=(f(y)-f(x_1))/(y-x_1),$$   $$s_2=(f(x_2)-f(y))/(x_2-y).$$ (Geometrically, $s_1$ is the slope of the line segment from $(x_1,f(x_1)$ to $(y,f(y))$ and $s_2$ is the slope of the line segment from $(y,f(y))$ to $(x_2,f(x_2).$)
 By the MVT there exists $z_1\in (x_1,y)$ and $z_2\in (y,x_2)$ with $f'(z_1)=s_1$ and $f'(z_2)=s_2.$ Applying the MVT to $f'$,there exists $z_3\in (z_1,z_2)$ with $$f''(z_3)=(f'(z_2)-f(z_1))/(z_2-z_1)=(s_2-s_1)/(z_2-z_1)>0,$$ contradicting the hypothesis that $f''\leq 0$ on $[a,b].$

For the case $n\geq 3,$ suppose it is true for case $n-1.$

Let $x^*_2=\sum^n_1w^*_i x_i$ where $w^*_i=w_i/\sum_2^n w_j$ for $2\leq i\leq n.$ By case $n-1$ we have $$\sum_2^n w^*_if(x_i)\leq f(\sum_2^nw^*_ix_i).$$

Let $x_2^*=\sum_2^nw_i^*x_1).$ We have $w_1x_1 +(1-w_1)x_2^*=$ $\sum_1^n w_ix_i.$

We have   $$\sum_1^n w_if(x_i)=w_1f(x_1)+(1-w_1)\sum_2^n w^*_if(x_i)\leq$$   $$\leq w_1 f(x_1)+(1-w_1) f(\sum^n_1 w_i^*x_i)=$$ $$= w_1f(x_1)+(1-w_1)f(x_2^*)\leq f(w_1 x_1+(1-w_1)x_2^*)=$$ $$=f(\sum_1^n w_i x_1). QED.$$

Although I proposed that $f''$ exists on an open interval containing  $[a,b],$ it is valid if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $f''$ exists and is $\leq 0$ on $(a,b).$ For example if $[a.b]=[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=\sqrt {1-x^2}.$ This requires showing that the MVT applies for $f$ and for $f'$ when $x_1=a$ or $x_2=b,$ where $f'$ or $f''$ might not exist.

In the instance $w_i=1/n$ for $1\leq i\leq n$  we have $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_1^n f(x_i)\leq f(\frac {1}{n}\sum_1^nx_i).$$

A particular case $f(x)=\log x$ for $x>0$ yields the AGM inequality. Since $f''(x)=-1/x^2<0,$ we  have,for positive $x_1,...,x_n$ $$(\sum_1^n\log x_n)/n \leq \log (\sum_1^n x_n).$$ Exponentiating this, we have $$(\prod_1^n x_i)^{1/n}\leq (\sum_1^n x_i)/n.$$